# Unable to call a method inside a property inside a class from a .NET DLL in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, dll

I have added a dll to my script and declared a new instance of a class from said dll.  I've been able to use all properties and methods from that class directly without errors as shown below:

```
$here = $PSScriptRoot
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $here 'AudioPrecision.API.dll')
#Declare a variable type APx500
$APX = New-Object AudioPrecision.API.APx500 -ArgumentList True
#Make the window visible
$APX.Visible = "True"
#open a specific project
$APX.OpenProject($here+"\test1.approjx")
```

Now, It is vital to me to use a method ( Run() ) which is inside a property (Sequence) which inside my already declared class instance.  I was able to access a property from said property as shown below:

```
($APX.Sequence.Count).Count
```

But when trying to access methods from that Property, it is not working.  I am trying the following:

```
$APX.Sequence.Run()
```

and I keep getting the following error:

*Method invocation failed because [System.MarshalByRefObject] does not contain a method named 'Run'.At C:\Users\eblacio\Documents\Hardware Validation\Audio tests automation\Powershell\Audio Precision API\AP 
automation.ps1:18 char:1
+ $APX.Sequence.Run()*

I've tried quite a few variants without success.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What type is `Sequence`? You need to make sure it is a member of a class or implementation of an interface which has the `Run()` method defined.

Comment: According to [this random thing I Googled](https://www.ap.com/analyzers-accessories/apx-overview/automation/) the Sequence.Run() method takes a parameter of a string containing a path to a project. `APx.Sequence.Run(“c:\\mytests\Test23.approj”)` - have you tried that form?

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton: If I do a Get-Member on $APX, the result for 'Sequence' is:Name :  Sequence                                         MemberType:  Property              Definition: AudioPrecision.API.ISequence Sequence {get;}      

The help file shows it as a public property. 

TessellatingHeckler: Yes I tried without luck.  The Run() method has 2 variants: with and w/o arguments. I've tried both without luck. .

Comment: And `($APX.Sequence).Run()` doesn't work, correct?

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton No it doesn't.  It throws the same error.